# Resolve the folder name in WinAPI

Tags: winapi, wildcard, filenames

I have a folder path like `c:\appfolder\user1.active\subfolder`. There are several folders in `c:\appfolder`, one per each user, but the active user's folder is marked by `.active` suffix.

Since there is only one marked folder, in the cmd console I can do anything with `subfolder` content, accessing it like this:

```
cd c:\appfolder\*.active\subfolder
delete myfile.txt
```

Unfortunately, I cannot access the file the same way in WinAPI, for instance, passing `c:\appfolder\*.active\subfolder\myfile.txt` to `CreateFile` or `MoveFile`. So, I should resolve the masked folder name into the first matching real folder name.

The question is: what's the simplest way to achieve this? I could use `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`, but as far as I remember they always return `.` and `..` at first, maybe there is a better approach, in a single function call?

Regards,

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It's inappropriate to vandalize your content here after you've received an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in single function to do what you ask. In my opinion there is no better way than to use `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`. You will have to deal with `.` and `..` but that's really not at all difficult.

Comment: You can wrap `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()` inside a custom function, say `GetActiveUserPath()`, and then use that function everywhere you need to access the active user's folder.